# React PWA - How do you detect if the requested data to be served from cache or from server

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am building a PWA app, where I download data by a user action call, "Go to offline". So once the button is clicked the data is fetched and saved to the browser indexdb storage.  I am using workbox and CRA2. I folled [this blog post](https://dev.to/divyansh7924/customizing-workbox-with-create-react-app-1ada) to customize workbox config with cra app.

Now say there is no PWA, and when page requests data, react call actions for example:

```
export async function fetchProjectStatuses(
  dispatch,
  params = {},
  raiseError = false
) {
  try {
    dispatch(requestProjectStatuses());

    const data = await fetchProjectStatusesApi();

    dispatch(receiveProjectStatuses(data));
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (raiseError) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      dispatch(requestProjectStatusesFailed(err));
    }
  }
}
```

and `fetchProjectStatusesApi` is defined as:

```
import axios from "axios";

const fetchAllUrl = () => `/project_statuses.json`;

export async function fetchProjectStatusesApi(config, params = {}) {
  const url = fetchAllUrl();

  const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
    headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
  });

  return data;
}
```

This works. Now when offline, I am trying to write something like:

```
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";

registerRoute(
  new RegExp("/project_statuses\\.json"),
  async ({ url, event, params }) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(event.request);
      const responseBody = await response.text();
      return new Response(responseBody);
    } catch (err) {
      // get from DB
    }
  }
);
```

So how do I write handler so that it forwards the data to the fetchProjectStatusesApi if network is present , else get data from DB. I know how to pull the date from local IDB. Only thing I am not able to figure out:

1. How do I detect the app is offline so the data has to come from local db
2. If app is online how do I forward the response from fetch to axios which is called from the api function.

I am writing it first time so I have no idea yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.